# How to edit active color of button in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4

I have the following piece of code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="validateForm()">Book appointment</button><br><br>
<p id="submitted" style="background:black"><p>
```

[image]
[image]

In black is the button and in green is the active button. How do I change the active color of this button? I have tried multiple things like:

```
.btn.btn-success:active{
background: #933A16;
}
```

Or

```
btn.btn-success:active{
    color #933A16;
    }
```

Or

```
.btn:active{
  color: #933A16;
}
```

And nothing has worked. It keeps showing up as that green color. I don't jave green anywhere else on the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you want to use `background-color` or `background`, I see you have `background` in your first example but `color` in the next two. You can also try to add the `!important` statement just before the semicolon to override bootstrap's settings.

If you are looking to change every button active color then you should like at Theming Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#color

If you just want to modify this single button you could add a custom class for it:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success custom-class" onclick="validateForm()">Book appointment</button><br><br>

.custom-class:active {background-color: green !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Burela said - adding '!important' will override the default for Bootstrap, so if you set the background-colour (rather than just background) to what you want with !important at the end, that is what will be used. Do this is a new class. Also, 'color' is used for the font, rather than the actual button.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define the enabled and disabled styles.
2. Assign and id to your button.

```
<button id="btnId" ...>
```

3. In the body of your function, add the following line to change the button style.

```
document.getElementById("btnId").className = "button disabled";
```

Check example below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .button {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      /* Green */
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .disabled {
      opacity: 0.6;
      cursor: not-allowed;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button class="button">Normal Button</button>
  <br>
  <button class="button disabled">Disabled Button</button>
  <br>
  <button id="btnId" onclick="validateForm()" class="button">Click once to disable</button>


  <script>
    function validateForm() {
      <!-- Do validation -->
      document.getElementById("btnId").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME! I'm disabled now";
      document.getElementById("btnId").className = "button disabled";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to change the button color when you tab to it, then you should use the “focus” option.

**The CSS styling.**

```
<style>
/* Set button default color */
.btn-primary{
    font-family: TimeBurner;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: #999;
    border-color: #222222;
    margin: 3em;
    padding: 1em;
}
/* Set button color on hover */
.btn-primary:hover{
    background-color: #ba321d;
    border-color: #000000;
}
/* Set button color when clicked on */
.btn-primary.active, 
.btn-primary:active
{
    background-color: #339933;
    border-color: #000000;
}
/* Set button color when tabbed to (active) */
.btn-primary:focus{
    background-color: #339933;
    border-color: #000000;
}
</style>
```

**On the html page.**

```
<button class="btn-primary">Button1</button>
<button class="btn-primary">Button2</button>
<button class="btn-primary">Button3</button>
<button class="btn-primary">Button5</button>
```